# Как создать БД Фамилия Имя Отчество через HashMap?

Tags: java, java-hashmap

Как создать БД Фамилия Имя Отчество через HashMap?
HashMap map = new HashMap<>();
Как добавить отчество и серию паспорта? Создать новый hashmap?

Comment: Сконцентрируйтесь на одном вопросе и постарайтесь расписать его как можно подробнее. Приведите свои попытки решения

Comment: Мап Это ключ-значение. Определите что должно быть ключем, а что значением

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да легко (правда не знаю зачем этот треш). Например так:

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

public class People {

    private static final Map <Long,People> PEOPLES = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    private static Long ID = 0L;

    private final Long id;
    private final String surname;    
    private final String name;
    private final String patronomic;
    private final String passport;

    private People(Long id, String surname, String name, String patronomic, String passport) {
        this.id = id;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.name = name;
        this.patronomic = patronomic;
        this.passport = passport;
    }

    public static People create(String surname, String name, String patronomic, String passport) {
       final People people = new People(++ID, surname, name, patronomic, passport);
       PEOPLES.put(ID, people);
       return people;
    }

    public static People getById(Long id) {
        return PEOPLES.get(id);
    }

    public static People deleteById(Long id) {
        return PEOPLES.remove(id);        
    }

    public static void deleteAll() {
        PEOPLES.clear();
        ID = 0L;
    }

    public static Collection<People> getAll() {
        return PEOPLES.values();
    }

    public static Long getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getPatronomic() {
        return patronomic;
    }

    public String getPassport() {
        return passport;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final People other = (People) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.surname, other.surname)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.name, other.name)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.patronomic, other.patronomic)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.passport, other.passport)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.id, other.id)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "People{" + "id=" + id + ", surname=" + surname + ", name=" + name + ", patronomic=" + patronomic + ", passport=" + passport + '}';
    }

}
```

А потом вызываем из другого класса статические методы для добавления, поиска по айди, получения списка, удаления , очистки:

```
public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        People.create("Pupkin", "Egor", "Ivanovich", "KK852741");
        People.create("Zalupkin", "Igor", "Aleksandrovich", "KK147896");
        People.create("Zalupupkin", "Ivan", "Ivanovich", "KK632147");

        System.out.println(People.getAll());
        System.out.println(People.getById(1L));
    }

}
```

Comment: Мы такую штуку делали на курсах тоже, хотя она не юзабельна от слова совсем. Ну ничего, парню нужно, а вы красиво написали всё, так сказать, оптимальненько)

Comment: Спасибо, но самое оптимальное в этом коде  - фамилии в БД))